# How to highlight dynamic words from response for different input string javascript, jquery, regex

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

[blog]: https://jsfiddle.net/kb413ae8/ "click here" for working fiddle

**Kids Markers & Crayons** is a response string for which highlighting of text should append, based on input we pass in **searchQuery** variable in code.

if **Markers** is provided as searchQuery input, Markers should be highlighted, which is currently working fine in above fiddle link.

if **space** is provided after word **markers** and pass has a searchQuery input in code, Kids **'b tag with class='boldTxt'>Markers** & Crayons is appended. which is weird. Happens same for all word with space.

Highlight of text/word should happen if **first** character in **searchQuery** input matches with **first character of word** in response. does not matter where the word is. Thanks

```js
var data = {"ResultSet":{"result":[
{"rank":"999999","term":"Kids Markers & Crayons"},
{"rank":"999999","term":"Crayola Fine Line Markers"},
{"rank":"999999","term":"Crayola Super Tips Washable Markers"},
{"rank":"999999","term":"Crayola Washable Markers Broad Line Classic"},
{"rank":"999999","term":"Post-it Assorted Page Markers"},
{"rank":"999999","term":"Crayola Markers Broad Line Classic"},
{"rank":"999999","term":"Crayola Crayons"},
{"rank":"999999","term":"Crayola Washable Markers Classic Colors"},
{"rank":"999999","term":"Crayola Washable Crayons Large"}]
,"totalResultsAvailable":"32","totalResultsReturned":11}};

for(i=0; i<9; i++) {
 var result = data.ResultSet.result[i].term;
 //console.log('result: ' + result);
 var searchQuery = 'Markers ';
 /*searchQuery inputs
   searchQuery = 'c'; o/p: c should be highlighted at beginning of word, In classic 'c' is highlighting twice which should not be highlighted at end or in mid of word.
   searchQuery = 'markers '; o/p: <b> tag is added which has to be removed.
   searchQuery = 'markers & c '; o/p: <b> tag is added which has to be removed.
   searchQuery = 'ola'; o/p: ola should be highlighted at beginning of word, In Crayola 'ola' is highlighting, which should not be highlighted at end or in mid of word.
 */
var searchResult = result;
words = searchQuery.split(' ');

$.each(words, function() { 

  var word = this.trim();
  var regex = new RegExp('(' + word + ')(?!>|b>)', 'gi');

  searchResult = searchResult.replace(regex, "<b class='boldTxt'>$1</b>");
});
console.log(searchResult);
$('#wag-typeaheadlists').append('<li><a>' + searchResult + '</a></li>')
}
```

```css
.boldTxt {
 color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="wag-typeaheadlists">
  
</ul>
```

Comment: Have a look at [mark.js](https://markjs.io/) to highlight text.

Answer (score 0):

In your fiddle try adding the following line after you split the searchQuery.

`words = words.filter(function(word){ return word != "" });`

Hope it solves your problem!

Comment: thank you, the above code solves spacing issue.word should be highlighted  if input string first character matches with first character of word from response. which still persits.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qp8ry0fL/ . working as expected but special characters are not highlighted. Could any one help me please.

Comment: If searchQuery  input is passed as 'markers c', the issue "Kids class='boldTxt'>Markers & Crayons" still exist. chaitan64arun could you please help me.